# call static method in another controller

Tags: php, yii

I want to call a static method in another controller to perform some global utility-like operations (update a file, for example). But I got a error message:

> include(AnotherController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

at */yii/framework/YiiBase.php(421)*:

> include($className.'.php');

Comment: Do you have a file */yii/framework/AnotherController.php*?

Comment: The code should be pulled out of the controller and put into a utility class.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu and Galen. AnotherController is a class I created myself. If I create a utility class, where should I put in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controllers are not autoloaded by Yii. Add the following to your configuration file:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.controllers.*',
    ...
),
```

Or, alternatively, just before you call a given controller, add the following line:

```
Yii::import('application.controllers.AnotherController');
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Willem. If I create a global utility class, where is the correct place to put in for Yii?

Comment: Probably the `protected/components` folder is best. By default, everything in that folder is autoloaded. Alternatively, you can create your old folder and just add it to the imports in your config file, much like you did with the controllers folder.